# What does `*` and `/` mean in def ()？

Tags: python

I found `*` , `/` in the `typing` source code, but I don't understand what it means.

```
def TypedDict(typename, fields=None, /, *, total=True, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

Anything before `/` means that the argument is position-only (see [PEP-570](https://peps.python.org/pep-0570/), while anything after `*`is keyword only (see [PEP-3102](https://peps.python.org/pep-3102/)). Anything in between can be both positional and keyword.